# Hash is not working on Array<UInt8> datatype in swift

Tags: swift, sha512, cbor

I'm trying to convert a payload using `CBOR.encode` method from `SwiftCBOR` which gives me a result in `Array<UInt8>` format and when the result is being hashed its gives the result in `Array<UInt8>` format but i need the hash of it

```
payload = {productName:"Philips Hue White A19 4-Pack 60W Equivalent Dimmable LED Smart Bulb"}

let payloadBytes = CBOR.encode(payload)
print("payloadbytes:",payloadBytes); // payloadbytes: [120, 83, 123,..., 98, 34, 125]

print("hashed payload",payloadBytes.sha512()); //[176, 26, 154,..., 85, 75, 77]
```

the expected output of hashing the `payloadbytes` is

> 6097B04A89468E7AAA8A1784B9CBAF0D2E968AFFC7F5AFE3B0B30CDF44A79EB41464EC773D0D729FA7E6AD6F7462EDEA09B34177CDB0D0DF4A6DDF3C6117C01E

Comment: Hi, the first line is not a valid Swift statement. How did you really create `payload`?

Comment: Yes it is not a valid swift Statement. Im just passing that value by some other means

Comment: so what type is `payload`?

Comment: It is JSON format only as represented. The input is coming from a QRScanner which is in this format only 
{productName:"Philips Hue White A19 4-Pack 60W Equivalent Dimmable LED Smart Bulb"}

Comment: let payload = [ "familyName": familyName, ] // this is valid format in Swift let payloadBytes = CBOR.encode(payload) print("payloadbytes:",payloadBytes); // payloadbytes: [161, 106,..., 108, 121] print("hashed payload",payloadBytes.sha512()); // [137, 225,..,169, 51, 232] still im getting the result in Array<UInt8> @JeremyP